# AJAX RETURN help on php/mysql dynamic drop down menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to populate one drop down menu based on the selection of the first drop down. The first drop down is a list of tables in my database, and the second drop down menu would populate from the providers within that table.

I am having trouble with the ajax script. I DO NOT KNOW how I can test ajax returns, I am fairly new to all this. But as of right now when I select the table from the first drop down menu, nothing happens(the second drop down menu is supposed to populate). I believe my issue lies within retrieving results from the ajax but that is only a guess.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My Javascript which sends the selction info from my specialist table to the ajax file...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery("flip").click(function(){
            jQuery("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
        });

        //provider drop down menu
        jQuery(".wrap").on('change','#specialist', function() {
            var querystr = 'specialist='+jQuery('#specialist :selected').val();
            jQuery.post("ajax.php", querystr, function(data) {
                if(data.errorcode ==0){
                    jQuery('#providercbo').html(data.chtml)
                }else{
                    jQuery('#providercbo').html(data.chtml)
                }
            }, "json");
        });

    });
</script>
```

My ajax file

```
$specialist = isset($_POST['specialist']) ? $_POST['specialist'] : 0;
if ($specialist <> 0) {
    $errorcode = 0;
    $strmsg = "";
    $sql="SELECT * from $specialist ORDER BY provider";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $cont=mysql_num_rows($result);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
        $chtml = '<select name="provider" id="provider"><option value="0">--Select Provider--</option>';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $chtml .= '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['provider'].'</option>';
        }
        $chtml .= '</select>';
        echo json_encode(array("errorcode"=>$errorcode,"chtml"=>$chtml));
    }else{
        $errorcode = 1;
        $strmsg = '<font style="color:#F00;">No Provider available</font>';
        echo json_encode(array("errorcode"=>$errorcode,"chtml"=>$strmsg));
    }
}
```

The HTML

```
<table id="dynamictable" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" border="3"  align="center">
        <tr><td>
                <div class="wrap" align="left">
                    <h3><strong>1.</strong>Specialist</h3>
                    <select id="specialist" name="specialist" required>
                        <option value="">--Select Specialist--</option>
                        <option value="addiction_specialist">Addiction Specialist</option>
                        </select
                </div></td>

            <td><h3 align="left"><strong>2.</strong>Provider</h3>
                <div class="wrap"  id="providercbo" align="left"></div></td>

    <table>
```

Comment: Firstly, stop using `mysql_*`, secondly send the values to javascript and build the HTML there, don't JSON encode an entire select and send it, and thirdly, the `if` condition in the ajax callback is useless, it does nothing ?

Comment: And, post the HTML as well

Comment: Most browsers have a web developer tab containing a Network watcher. Use this, trigger the AJAX op and see the request/response live as it runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up debugging on the PHP Side (XDebug works pretty well in most scenarios).  Also, for ANY AJAX/web request functionality, I run fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see what is being returned to the client from the web server (it will give you a complete view of the web request).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Very much! This pointed me in the right direction and now I know how to use ajax correctly. I changed up my script a bit and now it works perfectly. Thanks!